# Snow Leopard Terminal unable to write Capital P

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal

I cannot type a capital P on my Terminal, it automatically changes to "## adjust to taste".

I deleted all keyboard mappings under Terminal Preferences. I also reset all the Keyboard Mappings under System Preferences to their default values.

What else can I do? It is really annoying trying to avoid P's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and/or delete your `~/.inputrc` file. It's hidden, press `Cmd-Shift-.` in an *Open File* dialog to make it visible.

Comment: @Martin If this answer helped you, please click the checkmark next to it. The system then considers this question answered and rewards me with a few reputation points.